# WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

If you try to follow the [TensorFlow Linear Model Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide/) depending the version of tensorflow installed is a challenge complete the routine without errors.

I receive "WARNING:tensorflow:The default value of combiner will change from "sum" to "sqrtn" after 2016/11/01"

how is possible solve the warning?

**tensorflow: 0.12.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pay special attention to the definition of columns:

> tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(...)
>
> tf.contrib.layers.bucketized_column(...)
>
> tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column(...)

If you use version 0.12.1 the simple way to solve is including a modification of the parameter **combiner**

> tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(..., combiner="sqrtn")
>
> tf.contrib.layers.bucketized_column(..., combiner="sqrtn")
>
> tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column(..., combiner="sqrtn")

Comment: If of interest, the recent versions 1.0.0 of TensorFlow returns that same error message. Solution above also works with it.